# ASP.NET Core MVC posting a model to controller using ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core

I am trying to post a javascript object, representative of a Model, back to a controller using an ajax post. However, the model is always showing as null.

The model in question is as follows

```
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is required and must not be empty.")]
    [StringLength(200, ErrorMessage = "Name should not exceed 200 characters.")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public DateTime Created { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Price is required and must not be empty.")]
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

With the ajax call looking like so

```
$('#btnSaveNewProduct').click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var form = $('#frmNewProduct');
                if (form.valid()) {
                    var data = { // to be replaced with form values
                        Name: 'Bob',
                        Price: 34
                    };
                    //ajax call to save product
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "@Url.Action("AddProduct", "Admin")",
                        contentType: "application/json",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: data,
                        success: function (response) {
                            alert('done');
                        },
                        error: function (response) {
                            alert(response);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
```

The controller method looks like the following

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult AddProduct([FromBody] Product product)
    {
        bool success = false;
        // save product
        success = true;
        return new JsonResult(success);
    }
```

Any insight would be most appreciated.

Comment: `data: "json", data: data`?

Comment: `data: "json"` -> 'dataType: "json"`

Comment: May I ask why you are using a custom AJAX call instead of letting the View and Controller do the work for you?  For example, @using(Html.BeginForm() ... ) ?

Comment: I also suggest you look into AJAX Helpers.  Here is a C# Corner post about them: [https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/Asp-Net-mvc-ajax-helper/](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/Asp-Net-mvc-ajax-helper/).

Comment: @CodeBreaker Those are deprecated in ASP.NET Core

Comment: @CodeBreaker The AJAX helpers were never as good as AJAX calls. Besides, as  Marcel mentions, those don't exist anymore

Comment: @CodeBreaker because client side!

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Oops, mistyped data/dataType. Problem still remains however.

Comment: @Marcel forgot to update my post once I'd spotted it. Problem still remains however.

Comment: try `data: JSON.stringify(data),`

Comment: @Usman that's done it, thank you very much!

Comment: glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

To get your code to work as desired, make the following three modifications to your code.

- From the Ajax call, remove this: `dataType: "json"`
- From the Ajax call, remove this: `data:data`
- In the Ajax call, add this: `data:JSON.stringify(data)`

**IMPORTANT POINTS TO NOTE:**

1. When you are using the `[FromBody]` attribute, the `Content-Type` value determines the formatter for the ASP.NET Core MVC Framework to use for parameter binding.
2. Since your `Content-Type` is `application/json`, a **raw JSON string** and not a JSON object, should be passed as data. Hence, apply `JSON.stringify`.
3. See this reference: [Parameter Binding Using `[FromBody]` Attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api)

Answer (score 0):

I found below working:

```
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        data: { "Name": "bob", "Price": 10},
        url: "@Url.Action("AddProduct", "Admin")",
        success: function (data) {
            //success login
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert('error' + data.status);
        }
    });
```

no need to mention dataType and contentType in ajax call. And your controller will like below:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddProduct(Product product)
{
    //You logic will be here
}
```